# Reading and processing large shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, shapefile, error-999999

I have a large shapefile  (~10 Gb) which it output of Atoll (RF Coverage) and I need to perform some post-processing on it.

I began by importing the file in a file geodatabase, the file was imported without problems, but when I run a geoprocessing it raises errors of invalid geometries and the famous 999999. I tried to execute repair geometry but in vain.

I tried to import the shapfile in a PostGIS database using `shp2pgsql` but during the importing the process stops.

I am stuck on the problem for more than a week, any ideas of how to solve the problem?

Comment: What were the full error messages that you received from trying to Repair Geometry?

Comment: It is not possible to have a 10Gb shapefile. Any such file is hopelessly corrupt and cannot be safely read.

Comment: When i run Repair Geometry, the process  ends succesfully, but the file is still invalid because when I try to run another geoprocessing it raises the same error (invalid geometry), I tried to run Repair Geometry many times on the same file using an iterator but no result,

Comment: @Vince, that's the problem I guess, do you know how to split it into smaller pieces?

Comment: Whatever process is creating the corrupt file is at fault. That is where you need to address this.

Comment: as Vince say , shapefile is intended to be smaller than 2G per file. your data seems to be corrupted, the process creating the data is at fault here.

Comment: What do you suggest?